# Find table name of column name in SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have a string that contains a SQL query. And a string containing the name of one of the columns found in the query. How can I find the table from which the column is taken?

For example:

```
string qry = "select [firstName],[result] from [dbo].[patients],[dbo].results]";
string column = "firstName";
```

I want to get `[dbo].[patients]`.

Of course, the use will make complex queries and procedures more complicated also T-SQL.

Comment: What if your `from` clause has multiple tables?  What if it uses CTEs and/or sub-queries?  In general, you're asking how to build a SQL parser.  I think it's going to be a little too broad of a question to answer unless you can drastically restrict the input.

Comment: That value cannot be extracted from the SQL string on its own, nor can it be determined from the result of executing that statement. You would need to know the columns present in both tables in order to make that determination.

Comment: It gets even more complex if [dbo].[patients] or [dbo].[results] is a view and you actually do want to know the table.

Comment: It's worth noting the `TableA,TableB` join syntax is considered poor practice. It's been obsolete for a quarter century now.

Comment: There is a sql parser but it is not well documented. I don't know if it will suit your needs but worth a look: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.parser.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find out what the names of all the columns are in a database by using `sys.columns`. To find out what table, and schema that is in, you'd need to join to `sys.tables` and `sys.schemas`. Thus, using the example of the column name `[firstName]`:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) AS Object
FROM sys.columns c
     JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
     JOIN sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE c.[name] = 'firstName'
  AND t.[name] IN ('patients','results')
  and s.name = 'dbo';
```

Comment: You're not making use of the values in `qry` which the OP has indicated are important.  Your query will return *all* tables that have a column called `firstName` and not just the one used by the query.

Comment: This also assumes there are even any matches at all, and ignores the possibility the searched column is an alias name in the query.

Comment: The problem is not a matter of interrogating the catalog and finding matching tables/columns.  It's much more a matter of parsing a SQL statement to find the pieces used in the `from` clause which can vary based on the statement.  The OP indicates that some use cases will be more complicated than the example in the question.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, if we're going with the query `select [firstName],[result] from [dbo].[patients],[dbo].results]` then, no, there are no aliases. That is, of course, the query the OP supplied. This does, however, give the OP an insight into how to use the sys tables, and help them find their columns. But, like others had said, the person writing the SQL should really be putting aliases in there.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible in Sql Server for both tables to have the matching column names, and it's possible for the field from both tables to come back in a query with the *same name*. Moreover, you can have computed columns in a query where a result set includes information from both tables in a single column. There are other situations that can muddy things, as well.

Thus, you don't necessarily have enough information from just the column name to know with any certainty which table in a query sourced that column.

Comment: If your answer is _this can't be answered_, shouldn't this just be vote to close instead?

Comment: No. "How can I do X?" can still be a valid question, even when "You can't" is the correct answer.